# How to make custom column link to editform from default ListView

Tags: 2010

How is it possible to make a custom column or the default ID column on a list the link to the editform, form the deafult listview "AllItems".

I have a custom column "Heading" which I wanto to use as a link to the Editform/ViewItem. I think it is tedious to mark the check box and then the Edit button on the Ribbon menu.

I know I could rename the Title column but I prefere to avoid this, currently Title is hidden for the list.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do it by setting LinkToItem="True" attribute in the ViewFields element of your view. You can use SharePoint Designer, open your list and then your view and make change like shown below:

```
<ViewFields>
    ...
    <FieldRef Name="Status" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
    ...
</ViewFields>
```

This attribute is available from the Field definition

Comment: That provides a link but clicking it opens display form - how can I use it to open the edit form?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a calculated column similar to this:

```
=CONCATENATE("http://YourDomain/sites/SiteCollection/Lists/ListName/Forms/Editform.aspx?ID=",ID)
```

Sharepoint will turn this into a hyperlink automatically but will not let you display a pretty URL.

Another option would be to have a simple workflow fire on item creation to update a hyperlink field in your list to a specific value.

Another option would be to create a custom list view/dataview web part.  Then you can create the hyperlink on the fly and it is not stored in a column.